# Feed action request limit

Tags: facebook, api

Facebook post..
We have integrated our application with facebook. Everything is working fine and we have observed Feed action request limit reached (341) error.

We have checked the limit in privacy setting having arround 5M. Could you please let us know the limit (number for API's) once so that we will verify properly at our side.

Appreciate the immediate response.

Comment: Sounds like Facebook thinks you are spamming users...

Comment: Please do some research before you post here

Answer (score 0):

The API limit for Facebook is 600 calls per 600 seconds, per app & per IP. There are also application specific limits for limiting things like Feeds and Requests.

If you are hitting the limit you should seriously optimize your app to make less calls or batch requests.

Comment: That's not the feed action limit, that's the API limit, the feed action limit is 24 per user per 48 hours

Comment: The feed limit is different for every app. The more spammy it is, the lower the limit.